# Display The the result with comma seperated Using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

There are two tables in my Database

1. project - project_id (Nvarchar) , client_id (Nvarchar)
2. client -  id (int), name (Nvarchar)

Dependency- project.project_id=client .id

I want to create random column that display the client_name(comma seperated) which is stored in  Client table where client_id from project is depends on the id of Client table.

Here is a table and expected results-[image: Expected result]

Comment: which sql server version are you used

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)'

Comment: I used sql-2014

Comment: @NEER its not duplicate your answer is show only the stuff, its not show  join with the help of stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this Code

SELECT a.project_id, a.client_id, 
                        (
                            select ', '+co.name
                            from Client as co
                            where ','+a.client_id+',' like '%,'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,co.id)+',%'
                            for xml path(''), type
                        ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as client_name 
                    from project as a
```

Comment: its Working Thanx You so much